# epoch time / timestamps wireshark vs perf trace

Tags: linux, debugging, networking, wireshark, perf

I am trying to debug some issue on my Linux server:

Every 2 minutes I have some igmp query that I want to find source of.

From the Wireshark capture I see the exec time of the query:

```
**1488124556.773784** IP 0.0.0.0 > all-systems.mcast.net: igmp query v2
```

this time I can convert to real time without any problem:

```
**[root@server ~]# date -d @1488124556.773784: -> 
Sun Feb 26 10:55:56 EST 2017**
```

But When I try to trace the linux proccess with perf command:

```
perf trace -a -T -o trace.out
```

In the `trace.out`:

```
**15471296674.961** ( 0.023 ms): qemu-kvm/6621 ioctl(fd: 12<anon_inode:kvm-vcpu>, cmd: 0xae80                        ) = 0

**15471296674.979** ( 0.011 ms): qemu-kvm/6621 ioctl(fd: 12<anon_inode:kvm-vcpu>, cmd: 0xae80   
                     ) = 0

**15471296674.986** ( 0.004 ms): qemu-kvm/6621 ioctl(fd: 6<anon_inode:kvm-vm>, cmd: 0xc008ae67, arg: 0x7fbba66bf9d0  


15471296674.990 ( 0.002 ms): qemu-kvm/6621 ioctl(fd: 6<anon_inode:kvm-vm>, cmd: 0xc008ae67, arg: 0x7fbba66bf9f0  ) = 0

**15471296675.002** ( 0.010 ms): qemu-kvm/6621 ioctl(fd: 12<anon_inode:kvm-vcpu>, cmd: 0xae80  

**15471296675.009** ( 0.003 ms): qemu-kvm/6621 ioctl(fd: 6<anon_inode:kvm-vm>, cmd: 0xc008ae67, arg: 0x7fbba66bf9f0 


**15471296675.021** ( 0.010 ms): qemu-kvm/6621 ioctl(fd: 12<anon_inode:kvm-vcpu>, cmd: 0xae80                        ) = 0
```

I found the time is not in epoch format:

From the manual of perf page I found

> -T --time Print full timestamp rather time relative to first sample.

My question:

Is it possible to find the same timestamp format or type in Wireshark and perf trace tool ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are both wireshark and perf runs on the same machine (virtual machnine)? Is there same system time both on your VM host and in guest VM? Both tools should use unixtime (seconds from 1970): https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvTimestamps.html and perf (at least in `perf record` / `perf script` or `perf script -D` pair http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html)

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

Unfortuately, as of kernel 4.4, it is not possible to precisely convert perf-trace timestamps into unix time. You can roughly match them against time seen in /proc/uptime, but they drift apart since the boot with the difference measured in seconds or even minutes.

### Long answer

perf relies on sched_clock() which is tied to the number of nanoseconds since boot. For some reason perf puts a decimal point in a wrong place, so you see a number of seconds multiplied by 1000.

The problem is, numbers reported by sched_clock() are not actually accessible from the userspace. They're different from both CLOCK_MONOTONIC (can be seen in /proc/uptime) and CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW (can get it e.g. via clock_gettime syscall).

At least two patches were proposed to add kernel interfaces exposing sched_clock() into userspace, unfortuately both were rejected. I'm not aware of any successful attempts since then.

#### Rejected kernel patches:

- https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2273441/
- https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/3320271/

Comment: It's sched_clock_cpu() instead of sched_clock() if
CONFIG_HAVE_UNSTABLE_SCHED_CLOCK = y. Try `perf trace -T -- head /proc/sched_debug`
to get the difference between the two clocks. The diff is expect to
be `journalctl -k |grep -m1 "Marking stable" | awk '{print $NF}'` ns.